# Is there a simple Monero price lookup API?

Tags: api, php

I use cryptocompare.com for PHP lookups of Crypto-currency prices (i.e. 
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD). But they do not support Monero (XMN) for whatever reason. Is there anything similar for Monero?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're using the wrong ticker. Try XMR.

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XMR&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR

Answer (score 0):

These is an API to get Monero fiat prices:

See the main site: https://moneropric.es/

The JSON API is at https://moneropric.es/fiat.json and gets you a JSON object with the Monero exchange rate with various fiat currencies (as well as Bitcoin).